# Selection with data from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to search in two tables  **Input: User-ID ... Output: path**

tabel1

```
User-ID|Name|b1|b2|b3|b4
     0 |Per |1 |0 |1 |0
     1 |Lisa|1 |1 |1 |1
```

tabel2

```
Pic|path
b1 |"pics/001.jpg"
b2 |"otherpics/003.jpg"
b3 |"pics/002.jpg"
```

I want to use MySQL with PHP 
Exampel: User-ID=0(SELECT...)Output="pics/001.jpg","pics/002.jpg"

Thanks for your Support

Comment: Learn to normalize a database first.

Comment: Also this site is here to provide help with coding you have wriiten and are having problems with. **Its not for producing code from specifications**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalize your tables properly:

#### tabel1 (Users)

```
User-ID|Name
     0 |Per 
     1 |Lisa
```

#### tabel2 (Pics)

```
Pic|path
1 |"pics/001.jpg"
2 |"otherpics/003.jpg"
3 |"pics/002.jpg"
```

#### tabel3 (User_Pics)

```
User-ID|Pic-ID
0 | 1
0 | 3
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 3
```